# Esper Externally-timed view failed with time stamp ?

Tags: java, esper

So I need to compute events using esper with event time not the esper engine time.So first i have disable esper engine time and do the configuration.

```
esperServiceProvider = EPServiceProviderManager.getProvider("esperEventEngine", esperConfig); 
           esperConfig.getEngineDefaults().getThreading().setInternalTimerEnabled(false);
```

And then using this esper EQL i want to trigger event.In my event i have field called `private Date eventDateTime;`
The this is the EQL

```
select * from event.win:ext_timed(eventDateTime,20 sec)
```

But it gives this exception.

```
com.espertech.esper.view.ViewParameterException: Externally-timed view requires a timestamp expression and a numeric or time period parameter for window size
```

Have any one faced this problem.
Thanks
Sajith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When providing time to Esper using external timing, typically people use the time window (win:time). The ext_timed is then typically not used because time is already externally provided. I think ext_timed takes a long-value and not a Date.

Comment: Thanks this is the answer."ext_timed takes a long-value and not a Date"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have tried, the timestamp must be of long or int type.
In the official docs, it says that :

> The view takes two parameters: **the expression to return long-typed timestamp values**, and a time period or expression that provides a number of seconds